# Nginx logging in journal

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, syslog, journal

I'm using the latest nginx version (1.23.3) and latest rsyslog version (8.2212.0) in CentOS 7 and I'm trying to configure my nginx service for logging at the journal

> *journalctl -u nginx -f*

I have already configure nginx.conf to write the logs in /var/log/nginx and it is working.

> access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

under this line I'm trying to configure access_log for service logging in my console via - *journalctl -u nginx -f* - but it does not working

> access_log
> syslog:server=unix:/dev/log,facility=local1,tag=MY_NGINX,nohostname,severity=info
> combined;

It's weird because it was working, propable something with nginx or rsyslog version upate broke it. I have already check if its an issue with Selinux or read file permission.

Comment: Works for me with `nginx version: nginx/1.20.1`, latest CentOS 7 and `rsyslogd 8.24.0-57.el7_9.3`.